# Прошу подсказать по старту крупного проекта

Tags: java, микросервисы

Сейчас нахожусь на старте крупного проекта и не хочу наделать ошибок в самом начале. Разъесните пожалуйста непонятные мне нюансы:

1. Правильная ли схема приложения? Схема приложения: ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnY0H.jpg )
2. Нормальная ли практика, что один микросервис работает только с БД?
3. Могу ли я писать на последней версии Java?
4. Что даёт долгая поддержка у Java 8 и 11? Почему долгие проекты рекомендуют писать на них?
5. До этого писал на Java SE и не сталкивался с трудностями, нужна ли мне Java EE?
6. Под каждый микросервис (на том же Reg ru) нужно арендовать отдельный сервер?
7. Есть опыт деплоя PHP сайта. Говоря о Java, можно просто закинуть Jar или обязателен докер?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Правильная ли схема приложения? Схема приложения: (
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnY0H.jpg ) -  нет, не правильная, слишком
   вернеуровнево, так вы ничего не сделаете,учитывая, что вам
   необходима еще куча служебной информации
2. Нормальная ли практика, что один микросервис работает только с БД? - один
   микросеврсвис с одной бд, почему бы и нет, один микросервис и много
   бд, почему бы и нет, один микросервис и нет бд, почему бы и нет.
3. Могу ли я писать на последней версии Java? - можете, ограничений нет.  если
   вы используете поледние фитчи последний версии то вы должны писать на
   последней версии.
4. Что даёт долгая поддержка у Java 8 и 11? Почему долгие проекты
   рекомендуют писать на них? Потому что под эти версии легко найти
   разработчиков.
5. До этого писал на Java SE и не сталкивался с трудностями, нужна ли мне
   Java EE? ( j2ee это нормальный подход для клиент-серверных приложений.)
   Есть "страдальцы" которые пишут свои сервера приложений используя j2se.
   Если хотите страдать,пишите на j2se многопоточное приложение для обработки
   http запросов. И постарайтесь в нем реализовать все то что уже
   давно есть в j2ee.
6. Под каждый микросервис (на том же Reg ru) нужно арендовать отдельный
   сервер? Расчет производителности призводится с использованием  того
   программного обеспечения которое вы создаете.
7. Есть опыт деплоя PHP сайта. Говоря о Java, можно просто закинуть Jar или
   обязателен докер? Что такое PHP? Можно просто закинуть jar. Docker к java
   не имеет никакого отношения. Это все придумки младоумных, что без  docker
   жизни есть. Docker  это  система виртуализации (не лучшая),  но  к java  подходит

Comment: `Docker это система виртуализации (не лучшая)` а какая лучшая?

Comment: по  мне   так  лучше   vmware   ничего нет